# Set your own report default on send by email button in odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-9

I want to set my own created report default on `send by email` button. Means when i press `send by email` button, currently default report that is created by odoo is being sent. But i want to set my own report that is created by me.. Kindly please guide me how can i do it???? I'll be very thankful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reports are generated while using email templates. So just change the report in your email template to your own.

**Edit**: You will find the email templates at Settings/Technical/Email/Templates. Open the desired template (e.g. "Sales Order - Send by Email") and on the tab "Advanced Settings" you set up another report.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Means i couldn't understand your point . kindly please guide me, how can i change the report in my email template to my own